# Why Can't Embedded SharePoint Videos Be Viewed in Full Screen

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, video, bug

I'm using Microsoft Edge w/ Windows 10 and I'm embedding videos on SharePoint pages from the the Office 365 Video Portal.

For some reason the allow full screen code is being stripped out after the code is saved to the page. Take a peek to see what happens graphically and the 2 different versions of code.

[Is This a SharePoint Bug?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JrWIv76o93o)

Answer (score 0):

That is really annoying. I'm glad you pointed this out. I guess re-uploading a video using the Assets app is best so you get the Fullscreen option, but then it doesn't look like you get the variable quality options for lower bandwidth speed. No way to have both options.